# How to write xpath in selenium for Login link?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<a href="/MIS/PreLog/UserLogin.aspx" target="_blank">Login</a
```

I was trying to write the xpath for the above Login Link but it was not working.

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/MIS/PreLog/UserLogin.aspx') and  @id='login']" ).click();
```

Please give me the solution for this..

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide HTML, maybe there is simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In your xpath,

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/MIS/PreLog/UserLogin.aspx') and  @id='login']" ).click();
```

I don't see any `@id` attribute.

Also, why go for xpath specifically? You can use `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Login"))`

Edit 1 : Try this

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'UserLogin') and text()='Login']" )).click();
```

Comment: my page have two login text that's why it's not working on it.. Please suggest by using xpath.

Comment: See my edit. @kripindas selector is just missing an ending bracket.

Comment: @demouser123 Thank you for pointing out the issue. I have edited it now. I didn't tried in the editor so I missed the ending bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Your locator in the code can be modified and write like below, please check this should work,

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'UserLogin') and text()='Login']" )).click();
```

Comment: It is giving the error:- The method click() is undefined for the 
  type By

Comment: thanks @kripindas, also please explain why we have use * after //..??

Comment: @bharat  If it is worked then please accept the answer. If * is mentioned it will take from the node. If you are not using * before "//", the xpath locator will be incomplete and it will not work. Most commonly the class names or href will be starting after div or a (in your case), so in order to find the href we have to make use of * before the backslash. Also you can use **a** instead of *, it will also work, but what will happen is if **a** is changed to any other, it will not work. So it is better to use *.

Comment: I have tried this solution it worked only once after that it's not working..Please suggest what to do..??

Comment: @bharat  I had missed an ending bracket in the locator. That why it showed the error. I think the doubt about * is cleared now.

Comment: yeah , I understood the logic behind using *

Comment: @bharat It should work. I have checked. If not working it may be due to slow loading of elements in the web page. Please trying using a sleep before the step to check whether the issue of because of slowness.

Comment: @bharat  If it is worked, then please mark it as the answer.